# Puppet Dashboard - Directory Index Forbidden

Tags: ruby, apache, user-interface, puppet, dashboard

I also have issue on launching the Puppet Dashboard UI, Below is my config file. can anyone help me on this issue please.

Error I am getting :

`[Thu Aug 20 05:25:09 2015] [error] [client 192.168.XXX.XXX] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/`

Below is my VirtualHost file.

```
# UPDATE THESE PATHS TO SUIT YOUR ENVIRONMENT
#LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-5.0.15
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby

# you may want to tune these settings
PassengerHighPerformance on
PassengerMaxPoolSize 12
PassengerPoolIdleTime 1500
# PassengerMaxRequests 1000
PassengerStatThrottleRate 120
#RailsAutoDetect On
Listen 3000

<VirtualHost *:3000>
        ServerName puppetma.domain.net
        ServerAlias puppetma
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/
<Directory /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/>
                Options None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/puppet-dashboard_error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/puppet-dashboard_access.log combined
  ServerSignature On
```

I could see my DNS is absolutely working fine, I have also ensured stopping my host level firewall and selinux.

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
[admin@$$$]$ pwd
/usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public
drwxr-xr-x  5 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Apr  3 17:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 1006 Mar 21  2013 404.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard  989 Mar 21  2013 422.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 1.2K Mar 21  2013 500.html
drwxr-xr-x  3 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 images
drwxr-xr-x  2 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 javascripts
-rwxr-xr-x  1 admin            admin             18K Apr  3 17:46 puppet_dashboard.sql
-rwxr-xr-x  1 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard   26 Mar 30 15:42 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x  4 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 stylesheets

[admin@$$$]$ pwd
/usr/share/puppet-dashboard
drwxr-xr-x   17 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 .
drwxr-xr-x. 127 root             root             4.0K Apr  3 16:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x    7 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 app
drwxr-xr-x    2 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 bin
drwxr-xr-x    2 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 21  2013 certs
drwxr-xr-x    5 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:59 config
drwxr-xr-x    3 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 13:00 db
drwxr-xr-x    2 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 examples
drwxr-xr-x    4 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 ext
drwxr-xr-x    4 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 lib
drwxr-xr-x    2 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 31 03:24 log
drwxr-xr-x    5 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Apr  3 17:46 public
-rwxrwxrwx    1 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 1.7K Mar 21  2013 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x    3 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 script
drwxr-xr-x   10 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 spec
drwxr-xr-x    2 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 21  2013 spool
drwxr-xr-x    2 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 21  2013 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    5 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard 4.0K Mar 29 11:39 vendor
-rw-r--r--    1 puppet-dashboard puppet-dashboard    7 Mar 21  2013 VERSION
```

Comment: The issue seems to be that apache isn't able to find an index file and tries to list the directory content - which is forbidden due to `Options None`. 
Please have a look at https://wiki.debian.org/PuppetDashboard

There are some variables e.g. `RailsBaseURI /` which are not set in your vhost config.

Additionally: Is everything properly installed into the DocumentRoot ?

Comment: @mat1010 :  tried adding the "RailsBaseURI /" - still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help?

1) In the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`
change the:

`Options -Indexes` to `Options Indexes` (You may want to comment out the lines completely - depends what exactly you need).

2) Second thing maybe you just need to adjust the `+x` (execute) rights for your `/usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/` directory.

Try running `chmod 777 /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/` which will give all to users, group, world.  Please don't forget to adjust it correctly afterwards you are finished.  If you want to run the chmod recursively add `-R` option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168179/discussion-between-vasanth-nag-k-v-and-tukan).

Comment: @VasanthNagKV did not load properly the chat window for me.  Anyways, check your Passager configuration with `rvmsudo passenger-config validate-install` and paste the result?

Comment: sudo: rvmsudo: command not found i get this :(- i have not installed rvm

Comment: @VasanthNagKV how did you install ruby then?

Comment: i have installed it with yum. the tutorials i followed for the dashboard installation did not show me rvm.

Comment: @VasanthNagKV that is **not** necessary wrong.  I think it is good idea to have rvm on dev/testing environment (which I guessed you have).  On the other hand it is, in my eyes, preferred to have system wide ruby (generally you can check here with most of the post I agree - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559188/is-a-system-wide-install-of-rvm-a-bad-idea).  If you have installed it via `yum` please check it via `sudo /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install`.

Comment: i have run this and it says everything is fine.